# how to assure my implementation is in standard form (avoid bad coding)?

Tags: standards, recommendation-engine, code-standards

There are standard ways to implement most of the common funcionalities.
*For example* it is recommended to use `String Buffers` when concatenating larger Strings rather than using `Concatenating operator`.(which I randomly found)
Where can I find a collection of "recommendations" like this to avoid bad coding ?
There are a number of sites for "coding conversions" anyway.
(Googling didn't help.Do you have a better "search string"?)

Comment: The one about `String Buffers` is normally good only for big strings. If you have to add a fixed limited amount of strings, don't feel bad to do a+b+c.

Comment: I think the phrase you're looking for is "best practices," but note that what's "best" differs from community to community, application to application, and language to language.

Comment: @JohnFlatness thanks.That is the exact phrase.For example I found this in a millisecond [java best practices](http://www.javapractices.com/home/HomeAction.do).
Actually your comment is the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of *John Flatness*'s comment ,relevant Google search string would be "best practices".
some quickly found links for Java best best practices are 
[javapractices.com](http://www.javapractices.com/home/HomeAction.do),
[precisejava.com](http://www.precisejava.com/)

and for C#
[csharphelp.com](http://www.csharphelp.com/2010/02/c-best-practices-to-write-high-performance-code/),[codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CSharp_Coding_Practices.aspx)

[a link](http://www.precisejava.com/javaperf/j2se/StringAndStringBuffer.htm#Strings101) about the `StringBuffer`

Answer (score 1):

Have a read through...plenty of useful information.  [Google's coding standards for C++](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml)

Answer (score 1):

these things vary by language; what holds true for one may not for another. you probably should be googling "code smell" rather than "coding standards".